# Using AppConfig to import signals is not working Django 2.08

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-2.0

I have an app `companies`. Inside the app there is a file called `signals.py` with the following code:

```
post_save.connect(update_descendants, sender=Company)
```

Inside companies apps.py I have:

```
class CompaniesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.companies'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

But the signals are not imported/called.

If I import the file in models.py it work but it creates a circular import issue, and I need to this imports inside functions not at top.

Structure:

```
 - companies
   -apps
   -models
   -signals
```

Why app config is not working ?

Comment: I would say the name has to be without the _apps_ part: `name = 'companies'`.

Comment: @guillermochamorro there are inside a folder called apps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom AppConfig class then you need to tell Django about it. It isn't automatically discovered. Reference in in the Django settings files like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS [
    ....
    "companies.apps.CompaniesConfig",
    ....
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appconfig in app's **init**.py:

```
default_app_config = 'apps.companies.CompaniesConfig'
```

This is along with the ready() in AppConfig which I see you already have in apps.py

Comment: Correction, this should be `default_app_config='companies.apps.CompaniesConfig'`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an `__init__.py` file to the companies directory...

`__init__.py` can just be a blank file with that name.

Comment: it is a package so it has __init___.py